# Open GL: convert pan size in screen to world size

Tags: ios, opengl, graphics

I am implementing panning using two fingers in my ios 3D application. I have the translation value in screen coordinates (x,y). Now i need to move both the eye and center positions of the center in the right vector. The question is, how to i calculate the size of the vector - how mush i need to move the positions in world coordinates?

Comment: Perspective or orthographic projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the problem boils down to reversing the transformation pipeline. Since you're operating in a 3D space, but screen coordinates are 2D you must determine on a z value to augment the 2D screen coordinates; ether decide on a fixed reference plane or get the depth of the scene under the tap-midpoint.

In most cases the transformation pipeline is

```
NDC_to_Viewport ∘ Homogenize ∘ ViewSpace_to_ClipSpace ∘ ModelSpace_to_ViewSpace r
```

where `∘` denotes function composition.

The mapping from model space to clip space

```
r ⟼ ViewSpace_to_ClipSpace ∘ ModelSpace_to_Viewspace r
```

usually is implemented in terms of linear vector-matrix multiplication:

```
r_clip = P · V · M r
```

where `P` denotes the projection, `V` the view and `M` and model matrix. In OpenGL the view and model matrix are compound into the modelview matrix `MV = V · M` (keep in mind that order of operations matter with matrices, they're non-commutative).

Homogenization is what makes a perspective transform work: it's defined as

```
Homogenization: r ⟼ r/r_w
```

NDC_to_Viewport maps the range [-1;1] to the given viewport coordinates

```
NDC_to_Viewport: r ⟼ viewport_offset + viewport_extent * r / 2
```

Those are the operations you have to reverse. A practical implementation can be found in `gluUnProject` which source code is available from e.g. Mesa

```
/* transform a point in window coordinates (winx,winy,winz) into model space */
GLint gluUnProject(GLdouble winx,GLdouble winy,GLdouble winz,
                   const GLdouble model[16],const GLdouble proj[16],
                   const GLint viewport[4],
                   GLdouble *objx,GLdouble *objy,GLdouble *objz)
{
    /* inverse transformation matrices and vectors */
    GLdouble m[16], A[16];
    GLdouble in[4],out[4];

    /* map viewport coordinates to NDC range [-1;1] */
    in[0]=(winx-viewport[0])*2/viewport[2] - 1.0;
    in[1]=(winy-viewport[1])*2/viewport[3] - 1.0;
    in[2]=2*winz - 1.0;
    in[3]=1.0;

    /* determine inverse transformation matrix */
    matmul(A,proj,model);
    invert_matrix(A,m);

    /* transform NDC space coordinates to model space */
    transform_point(out,m,in);
    if( fabs(out[3]) < 1e-6 ) {
       /* singular transformation, can not back transform. */
       return GL_FALSE;
    }

    *objx=out[0]/out[3];
    *objy=out[1]/out[3];
    *objz=out[2]/out[3];

    return GL_TRUE;
}
```

With the back projected positions of the movement's start and end point you get a differential vector which you can apply to your camera's position and target points.